# Jest unable to load module vue-cookies

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
  [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

  found in

  ---> <Anonymous>
         <Root>
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1884
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
      at VueComponent.mounted (/home/ubuntu/vue-testing-skel/src/components/ChatApp.vue:66:1)
```

The line that is causing the error:

```
    this.current_nickname = this.$cookies.get('nickname')
```

`this.$cookies` is provided by a module called `vue-cookies`

I have it installed and saved in my devDependencies, but it seems jest is unable to find it or load it.

I'm not sure what I have to do to make sure Jest is loading these modules properly.

Answer (score 3):

Testing with Jest is meant to be self-contained. This means that global objects like this.$cookies are not available since they are interfacing with the cookies in your browser. The way to solve this is to mock the global functions. More info on how to do that here:
https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/mocking-global-objects.html#example-with-vue-i18n

Answer (score 0):

To build off of [@Imre_G 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56378373/625840), you need to specify a `$cookies` key inside your `mount()` or `shallowMount()` function, like so:

```
    wrapper = shallowMount(ComponentName, {
      localVue,
      ...
      mocks: {
        $cookies: {
          get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(null),
          set: jest.fn(),
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Also, in case this helps anyone else, make sure you're using `this.$cookies` in your components and not using the global `$cookies` object. Both are available to use from the `vue-cookies` library, but mocking in your tests like this only overwrites items within the scope of the component, not the global scope.